# Drupal 7 Bamboo theme maintenance mode

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to make a custom maintenance page for Bamboo theme in Drupal 7.
I already follow some tips I have found in internet, but they don't work.
The site is in maintenance mode, but with a layout totally different from the rest of the theme (it is a simple logo with the message "site in maintenance ..."
In the theme there isn't a template named maintenance-page.tpl.php in root theme directory neither in subdirectory templates.
I created a new file copied from html.tpl.php in both directory, but without success.
Some advice? What should I do?

Thanks in advance,
Mauro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can copy the maintenance-page.tpl.php from Bartik (default
   Drupal theme) and paste it to you theme folder
2. Customize the new file maintenance-page.tpl.php

Comment: Thank, I have done this way, but I can't include a custom css only for maintenance page. I have create a function in template.php named bamboo_preprocess_maintenance_page in which I use the function drupal_add_css, but the css is not loaded. What shoud I do to load a custom css? Even the local.css is not loaded!

Comment: Create your css file (for example local.css), add it to your theme css folder, add this file to the template.info file (for example stylesheets[all][] = css/local.css) and finaly flush caches.

Comment: Does the local.css load in other pages?

Comment: If you add CSS via .info file, it'll be loaded on all pages. How about just add `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` or `<style></style>` to the `<head>` section of your maintenance-page.tpl.php? Not a Drupal-style but should work :)

Comment: PS Are you sure that this code in template.php `function YOURTHEME_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) { drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME') . '/custom.css'); }` doesn't work? For me it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks to all, I solved the css problem. @ProjectAO: I add the line into the .info file: stylesheets[all][] = css/maintenance.css. I already have the overload preprocess function in my template.php. The problem was that the local.css were loaded correctly though not in .info file. In the Bamboo theme there is an option into the theme settings of Drupal interface, and isn't necessary to explicity add the css in .info file. I mark this question solved! Now I'am going to customize the css.